# multiple search condition sql

Tags: sql, search, notin

Is it possible to achieve something like this in sql?

```
ID!= {2,3}
```

where ID is a column. Or I have to use multiple OR statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, `not in`:

```
ID not in (2,3)
```

You can read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx).

Comment: or `not ID in (2,3)` - I've had problems with the above syntax in the past - especially when dealing with NULL values.

Comment: @MattTew. NULL values is DB are "nothing" so you need to be careful with those. And different `DBMS`s can handle it other way. But except that, what kind of problems did you have with `not in`?

Comment: I can't say off hand.  I just know that I have scratched my head in the past wondering why NOT IN wasn't working, but reversing the syntax worked (using MySQL).  I think I was also using a subquery to get the set.  Your answer is correct (and I upvoted it), just adding my 2c.

Comment: @MattTew. ohh subqueries, Now I get it. You should use `EXIST` or `NOT EXIST` with NULL subqueries.

Answer (score 3):

You have to try With

```
ID NOT IN (2,3)
```

Or

```
ID <> 2 or ID <> 3
```

Comment: You probably meant: `id <> 2 **AND** id <> 3`. Your condition will always be true.. id can't be equals to 2 **and** equals to 3 at the same time!